# pushing django migrations into source control

Tags: django

I've deployed my Django application for a while now, but all this time I've kept migrations out of souce control. What I did was run `makemigrations` and `migrate` twice-- once in development, and once in production. So now how can I seamlessly put my migrations into source control? Theoretically the migrations should be the same (given my `models.py` files haven't changed), but how would I go about matching my migrations up without accidentally overriding something?

Comment: As long as you are running the same code base on both, and have updated migrations, you need not worry

Comment: `git status -> git add migration..... -> git commit -> git push`

Comment: Add your production migrations into source control (delete migrations in dev env and pull). If anything goes wrong (because the migrations are not the same), just get a fresh dump of your prd database to develop with. This prevents trouble on your next deploy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand the problem...

Django keeps track of which migrations have been applied using the database. But it uses the names, not the contents. So as long as you're not changing the contents of migrations that have already been applied, you should be good.